# How to use django-dbbackup?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, backup

I am trying to use the [django-dbbackup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbbackup) tool to backup my PostgreSQL database. I have setup everything as written in the documentation. However, when I run in the python shell:

```
import dbbackup
dbbackup
```

I get:

> module 'dbbackup' from
>   '/Users/poiuytrez/.virtualenvs/ariseio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbbackup/**init**.pyc'

I am not sure on how to use the tool.

Comment: is that the full error that you get?

Comment: according to the doc, you should run dbbackup as a command, not importing it in your codes

Comment: @glasslion Is there any way to run this command from django instead of outside with python manage.py? I am trying to run it inside a celery task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I needed to run the command using the manage.py file:

```
python manage.py dbbackup
```

It was not very explicit in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation in the project, https://bitbucket.org/mjs7231/django-dbbackup .Its explicitly mentioned on how to add the settings for the backup package to run and once you have setup everything, all the other are management commands..e.g `python manage.py dbbackup`. To check on which management commands are available for dbbackup package, just run `python manage.py help`. This will display all commands under their respective packages.

```
[dbbackup]
    backup_media
    dbbackup
    dbrestore
```

To answer your question 'dbbackup'  is a django management command just like syncdb, hence run it using `python manage.py dbbackup`.